# In Django RestFramework, how to change the Api Root documentation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, docstring

In django RestFramework, is there any "official" way to generate the documentation for the "Api Root" ?

After looking at the RestFramework's source code, I've found a work around by subclassing the DefaultRouter:

```
from rest_framework import routers

class MyRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    def get_api_root_view(self):
        api_root_view = super(MyRouter, self).get_api_root_view()
        ApiRootClass = api_root_view.cls

        class MyAPIRoot(ApiRootClass):
            """My API Root documentation"""
            pass

        return MyAPIRoot.as_view()

router = MyRouter()
```

Is there a cleaner or better way ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm new to this but I found you can use a [`SimpleRouter`](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers.html#simplerouter) instead of a `DefaultRouter` to specify your own `APIRoot`.

in `urls.py` in your api module

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
router = SimpleRouter()

urlpatterns = patterns('api.views',
    url(r'^$', views.APIRoot.as_view()),
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
)
```

Then specify the documentation in the class comment

```
from rest_framework import generics

class APIRoot(generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    My API documentation
    """
```

ㄑ

Comment: with your approach, using `SimpleRouter` or `DefaultRouter` doesn't really matter. You can still use `DefaultRouter` without any problem. Especially if you need the [**format suffix**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) provided from it.

Comment: What would be the best way to do the same thing, but not break anything else? I mean this completly overwrites the normal API root view, so things might stop working.

Answer (score 23):

I found a solution through experimentation.

I prefer it to the other solutions in this thread as it requires less code and allows you to customise the API title, as well as the documentation for the API root.

```
from rest_framework import routers

class ThisWillBeTheApiTitleView(routers.APIRootView):
    """
    This appears where the docstring goes!
    """
    pass


class DocumentedRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    APIRootView = ThisWillBeTheApiTitleView


router = DocumentedRouter()
router.register(r'items', ItemsViewSet)
```

This renders as below:

[image: Demonstration]

Comment: I've you dive a bit deeper to bring you the knowledge of these settings:

- VIEW_NAME_FUNCTION = 'rest_framework.views.get_view_name'
- VIEW_DESCRIPTION_FUNCTION = 'rest_framework.views.get_view_description'

So your class just need to define it's *name* and *description* property to render what you need.

Answer (score 16):

If anyone wants an inline style

```
   router = DefaultRouter()

   router.get_api_root_view().cls.__name__ = "Root API name"
   router.get_api_root_view().cls.__doc__ = "Your Description"
```

Comment: Be careful. This will set the name of the APIRootView itself, which will apply to all DefaultRouters in the system.

Answer (score 5):

It's kind of difficult to override the APIRoot class. The most simple way to achieve what you want is probably to modify the `__doc__` attribute of the APIRootClass at runtime in your `urls.py`:

```
class Router(routers.DefaultRouter):
    def get_api_root_view(self, api_urls=None):
        root_view = super(Router, self).get_api_root_view(api_urls=api_urls)
        root_view.cls.__doc__ = "Place your documentation here"
        return root_view

router = Router()
router.register(...)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: In Python 2 you get an exception trying to write `__doc__`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [frost-nzcr4's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496249/in-django-restframework-how-to-change-the-api-root-documentation#comment102438830_44262709) above, I found a nice way to do this:

```py
from rest_framework import routers
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class MyAPIRootView(routers.APIRootView):
    """
    Controls appearance of the API root view
    """

    def get_view_name(self) -> str:
        return "My API"

    def get_view_description(self, html=False) -> str:
        text = "My REST API"
        if html:
            return mark_safe(f"<p>{text}</p>")
        else:
            return text


class MyRouter(routers.DefaultRouter):
    APIRootView = MyAPIRootView
```

Then use this router in your `urls.py`:

```py
router = MyRouter()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'snippets': reverse('snippet-list', request=request, format=format)
    })
```